# InDesign, Grep - what is the base syntax of InDesign grep

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep, regex

There are many regex syntax, one different from the other: **.Net** regex, **Java** regex, **PHP/PCRE** regex, **Python** regex. etc.

Some sites for checking & testing regex expressions are just great - like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) [that is mentioned on [InDesignSecrets](https://indesignsecrets.com/resources/grep) grep resources], but it has different languages/syntax.

For example: The RegExr supports only JavaScript and PHP/PCRE. But the [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) supports only .Net.

**On what exact syntax the InDesign grep is based on?**
Thanks you very much for your kind help.

Edit: to be more clear - on [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) it is called 'regular expression engine' or 'regular expression flavor'. So what is the InDesign 'regular expression flavor'?

Comment: I just can assume that 'InDesign grep flavor' is PCRE (Perl based): just trying to use 'R' expression (=[Recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)) and [this one](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) worked great on InDesign. And it is not supported on all engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer for this question on the [Adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10936981#10936981). 
This what is says:

> According to Peter Kahrel's title "[GREP in InDesign 3rd Edition](https://indesignsecrets.com/now-available-grep-in-indesign-3rd-edition.php)" (ISBN: 978-0-9825083-6-7) - InDesign’s GREP uses the Boost libraries; information on these libraries is available from www.boost.org, especially [Perl Regular Expression Syntax - 1.67.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)